# Terraform Enterprise container failed with Flexible deployment with Disk Option

Tags: devops, terraform-enterprise

I have a TFE server configured with FDO and Disk options, and it was running successfully. However, after a restart, it failed to start, displaying the following error:

{"log":"2024-02-16T05:21:39.086Z [ERROR] terraform-enterprise: startup: error="exit status 7"","component":"terraform-enterprise"}

Additionally, there is a warning message:

{"log":"2024-02-16 06:04:23,340 WARN No file matches via include "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf"","component":"supervisor"}

I tried with clean installation.